# QuickBasic optional arguments

Tags: optional-parameters, dosbox, qbasic, quickbasic

Is it possible to write a subroutine or function with optional arguments?

for example:
`MyFunct (x AS INTEGER, [y AS INTEGER, Z AS INTEGER])`
so that I can use the function with only the first argument and sometimes with all arguments, in the same program, like the following for example:
`Myfunct 5`
`MyFunct 5,6,7`

Also, is it possible to write a sub or a function that takes arguments in format that is used with some of the graphics commands in QuickBasic, like the WINDOW and LINE.. For example:
`WINDOW (10,50)-(100,100)`
`LINE (10,10)-(50,50`

I tried using square brackets, [], because the manual said those represent the optional arguments, but I guess it is only for reading the syntax conventions. Is there any way to have optional arguments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the way I would do it would be to pass your arguments in a string, separated by some delimiter. Then you can break the variables out of the string once in the function with logic to handle if the argument is missing.

MyFunc (“x=1,y=2,z=3”)

*String parser left as an exercise for the OP*